# New to Javascript, can someone explain this code line by line?

Tags: javascript

I used this code to maintain scroll position and don't have a clue of what it means.  If someone has the time, can you provide me with an step by step explanation of what it is doing.  Here it is:

```
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {

            xPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft;
            yPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop;
        }
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

        if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {

            $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft = xPos;
            $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;
        }
    }

    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

</script>
```

Comment: This codes helps to maintain scroll's position between every MS ajax postback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var xPos, yPos; // global variable declaration
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); // Some webforms javascript manager

/*
* Begin function with 2 arguments
*/
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

    // check if the element generated by .net with id 'lstAuctions.ClientID' exists
    if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {

        // get its scroll left and top position and
        // assign it to the global variables
        xPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop;
    }
}

/*
* this method gets executed last, it uses the 
* already set global variables to assign the old scrollpositions again
*/
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

    if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {
        // assign the previous scroll positions
        $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
}

// first function gets executed on the beginning of a request
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
// second function gets executed on the end of the request
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks!  What exactly is the beginRequest and endRequest?  Is this similar to the Page_Load and Page_Unload in asp.net?

Comment: From MSDN, I never used it personally.

beginRequest = Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.

endRequest = Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.

Comment: beginRequest and endRequest are (likely) DOM-based custom events. The prm object has some easy syntax to assign your function to be called. Based on the naming, beginRequest and endRequest sound like pre- and post- function calls in some AJAX request.

Answer (score 4):

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398822.aspx) is an ASP.Net AJAX construct.

Specifically in your code, there are some allocated variables (xPos,yPos,prm) and two defined functions (BeginRequestHandler,EndRequestHandler). At the end of the code are two function calls (prm.add_beginRequest,prm.add_endRequest) that are assigning those functions as event handlers.

The $get calls are part of the library as a shortcut for getting data from the client-side. It's very much javascript under the covers, but it's just a syntactical implementation through the ASP.Net AJAX client-side library.

Comment: So instead of $get, what could I have used?

Comment: Use $get because the .net generated ID's are only known after page generation. With less crappy implementations of generated code (I really hate asp.net for those ID's) you can use document.getElementById(<id here>);

Comment: ok, so I can either use $get or document.getElementById().  $get is just an microsoft shortcut, is this correct?

Comment: yes, $get() appears to be a shortcut to document.getElementById(). Pay heed to Tomh comment about generated Ids on the client-side.

Comment: $get is not a shortcut, .net generates ids like ctl_001_001_originalId if you use originalId as id in your aspx page. You do not know this prefix, thats why MS thought it was handy to build a function which does know that prefix so you can just use the id you assigned and the function adds the rest.

Comment: tomH, are you sure $get() is not a shortcut? In this line of code:
$get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>')
the clientID value will be rendered correctly at runtime, but I believe $get is written to the page. Thus, it should map to javascript routine in the JS client libs.

Answer (score 2):

You did ask...

```
// declare 2 variables
var xPos, yPos;
// get an instance of the PageRequestManager - this looks like an MS ajax helper class
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

// declare a function
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

    // get the ClientSide HTML DOM element which corresponds to the lstAuctions asp control on the serverside
    if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {
        // if the element is not null (eg: page is not broken)

        // get the x Position of the object relative to what is displayed by the scrolled window (if you scroll sideways this value changes)
        xPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft;
        // get the y Position of the object relative to what is displayed by the scrolled window (if you scroll up/down this value changes)
        yPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop;
    }
}

// declare a function
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

    // get the ClientSide HTML DOM element which corresponds to the lstAuctions asp control on the serverside
    if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {
        // if the element is not null (eg: page is not broken)

        // set the x position of the object to what we got last time (horizontal scroll the page)
        $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft = xPos;

        // set the y position of the object to what we got last time (vertical scroll the page)
        $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
}

// tell the page request manager to call our BeginRequestHandler method when it begins it's request
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

// tell the page request manager to call our EndRequestHandler method when it ends it's request
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Basically, it looks like the page is using the MS ajax library to display some dynamic content (probably replacing a list with another list), but preserving the place that the user has scrolled to so the page doesn't "jump" when the new content replaces the old content.

Comment: Thanks, what is the $get for and can the BeginRequestHandler and EndRequestHandler be named anything?

Answer (score 1):

[scrollLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534617(VS.85).aspx)

[scrollTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534390(VS.85).aspx)

[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

var xPos, yPos;

**declares two global variables.

---

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

**declares a new function.  This function is probably used for an event handler

if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {

**this is a combination of inline ASP/ASP.NET code as defined in the <% %> pairing.

xPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft;

**captures the current scrolling position of the page into the local variable.

yPos = $get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop;

**captures the current scrolling position of the page into the local variable.

---

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

**declares a new function.  This function is probably used for an event handler

if ($get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>') != null) {

**this is a combination of inline ASP/ASP.NET code as defined in the <% %> pairing.

$get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollLeft = xPos;

**sets the scrolling position of the page to the value of xPos.

$get('<%=lstAuctions.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;

**sets the scrolling position of the page to the value of xPos.

---

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

**declares and initializes a new variable to the PageRequestManager.

prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

**adds the event handler defined above to the beginRequest of the current page.

prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

**adds the event handler defined above to the endRequest of the current page.